# Update part of a string included between delimiters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I have to update a text column that is a list of strings separated by a `|`. I want to replace the second string with an empty text.

Column values example:

```
TD_DM_U100|BK_U100|TL_DM_U100||||
TD_DM_U200|BK_U200|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT||
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|
```

Result after update (remove the second string)

```
TD_DM_U100||TL_DM_U100||||
TD_DM_U200||TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT||
TD_DM_U300||TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Is version 2016

Comment: As you're on 2016 you could consider using the STRING_SPLIT function. Example here to get you started.  SELECT
 value
FROM
 STRING_SPLIT('TD_DM_U100|BK_U100|TL_DM_U100||||', '|');

Answer (score 0):

You can update with contribution of `charindex()` and `substring()` functions

```
update tab
   set col = replace(col,substring(col,charindex('|', col),len(col)),'||')+
             substring( substring(col,charindex('|', col),len(col)), 
                                      charindex('|', col),len(col) );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9cd7ba5e8df9a9f1a5df431cb62651e8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a21157cfa0036766daef89e3a5679d66)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

DECLARE
    @val VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE
    @TestData TABLE
    (
        Id INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
        Col1 VARCHAR(100)
    );

DECLARE
    @i INT = 1;

INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    'TD_DM_U100|BK_U100|TL_DM_U100||||'
),
(
    'TD_DM_U200|BK_U200|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT||'
),
(
    'TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|'
);

DECLARE
    @Result TABLE
    (
        Col1 VARCHAR(100)
    );

WHILE @i <=
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            @TestData
    )
BEGIN

    SET @val = NULL;

    SELECT
        @val = COALESCE(@val + '| ' + v.Col1, v.Col1)
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                (
                    SELECT
                        1
                )
                ) rn,
                value
            FROM
                STRING_SPLIT(
                (
                    SELECT
                        Col1
                    FROM
                        @TestData
                    WHERE
                        Id = @i
                )
                , '|')
        ) t1
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT
                    CASE
                        WHEN rn = 2 THEN ''
                        ELSE value
                    END
            ) v (Col1);


    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT
        @val;

    SET @i += 1;

END;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanations:**

One possible approach is to parse and manipulate your text values using `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `CHARINDEX` and `LEN` functions. Next statement demonstrates this approach:

```
-- Statement
DECLARE @Text varchar(max) = 'A|B|C|D|'
SELECT 
   LEFT(@Text, CHARINDEX('|', @Text)) AS LeftPart,
   RIGHT(@Text, LEN(@Text) - CHARINDEX('|', @Text)) AS RightPart

-- Output
LeftPart RightPart
A|       B|C|D|
```

**Solution:**

In your case, because you need to change the second part of the text, the statement will be more complicated:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [Text] varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   ([Text])
VALUES
   ('TD_DM_U100|BK_U100|TL_DM_U100||||'),
   ('TD_DM_U200|BK_U200|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT||'),
   ('TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET [Text] = CONCAT(
   LEFT([Text], CHARINDEX('|', [Text])),
   '|',  -- Or use some different value
   RIGHT(RIGHT([Text], LEN([Text]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Text])), LEN(RIGHT([Text], LEN([Text]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Text]))) - CHARINDEX('|', RIGHT([Text], LEN([Text]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Text]))))
)
```

Output:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Data
--------------------------------------------
Text
--------------------------------------------
TD_DM_U100||TL_DM_U100||||
TD_DM_U200||TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT||
TD_DM_U300||TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|
```

**Notes:**

Just as additional information, another possible approach in your case is to transform each text into a table, update rows in this table and then aggregate table's rows into a text. SQL Server supports [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (from SQL Server 2016) and [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (from SQL Server 2017) functions, but in your specific case this is not an option. The reason is, that `STRING_SPLIT` not guarantee the order of the substrings in the output table.

> The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to
>   match the order of the substrings in the input string. You can
>   override the final sort order by using an ORDER BY clause on the
>   SELECT statement (ORDER BY value).

In this case, when the order of the each substring is important, you may use `JSON` or `XML` transformations. Next basic example demonstrates this using `JSON` capabilities:

```
-- Statement
DECLARE @Text nvarchar(max) = N'TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT|'
SELECT 
   @Text AS [Text],
   j.[key] + 1 AS Position,
   j.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(@Text, '|', '","'), N'"]')) j

-- Output
Text                                                Position value
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 1        TD_DM_U300
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 2        BK_U300
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 3        TL_DM_L100
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 4   
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 5        SOME TEXT
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 6        MORE TEXT
TD_DM_U300|BK_U300|TL_DM_L100||SOME TEXT|MORE TEXT| 7
```